# Show that the argument form with premises (p ∧ t) → (r ∨ s), q → (u ∧ t), u → p, and¬s and conclusion q → r is valid. (Is my solution correct?)

Tags: logic

Here is my solution/proof

1. (p ^ t) -> (r v s) //Premise
2. q -> (u ^ t) // Premise
3. u -> p // Premise
4. ~s // Premise
5. q -> u // Simplification of (2)
6. q -> t // Simplification of (2)
7. q -> p // Hypothetical Syllogism (3) (5)
8. q -> (p^t) // Conjunction
9. q -> (r v s) // Hypothetical Syllogism (1) (8)
10. ~q v ( r v s) // Logical Equivalence, Conditional Statement
11. ~q v ( s v r) // Commutativity
12. ~q v r // Disjunctive Syllogism
13. q -> r // Logical Equivalence

Thanks in advance to anyone who can point out any mistakes or suggestions! <3

Comment: Line 12 should indicate which lines it's combining (11) and (4)

Comment: Oh okay, so is Line 12 the only problem?. Line 12 is a Disjunctive Syllogism, working on Line 11, specifically on ( s v r), since s v r, if ~s, then r, so the result was r, and then ~q v r. Is that correct?

Comment: I have a question tho, do I need to use up all the premises in the proofs? I have stated the premise ~s, though, I didn't really use it in anything. Is it ok?

Comment: @Kristofer You have used it in Line 12.   But also, no, you do not *need* to reference every premise.

Comment: PS: Line 11 should preferably be commuted and associated to $s\lor (\lnot q\lor r)$ to make the application of Disjunctive Syllogism stricter.  $$\dfrac{s\lor (\lnot q\lor r), \lnot s}{\lnot q\lor r}{\small\lor\mathsf S}$$

Comment: Okay, but I'm confused on where to put ~s on the change you suggested. Should I add another line that has ~s v s?

Comment: No. @Kristofer The rule is that when you have $s\lor(\lnot q\lor r)$ and $\lnot s$, then you may infer $(\lnot q\lor r)$ by rule of Disjunctive Syllogism.  You *do* have $\lnot s$ on line 4, and *mostly* have $s\lor(\lnot q\lor r)$ on line 11 , so that is all you need.  Just add the line numbers to the justification on line 12.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a *strict* adherence to the fundamental rules of inference in any system I'm familiar with.   *However* each inference you've made is **valid**.   They *may* need additional steps to derive them -- depending on the set of rules you are *allowed* to use and how they are implemented.

---

Also, as TomKern suggests, you should include line references with *every* justification.